# Thingboard widget HTML card issue: How to display FFT graph from custom data

Tags: javascript, html, thingsboard

I'm new to HTML and I've tried to visualize a custom data array using an example code.
While the example code can display, when I replace the hardcoded value with url fetched data, there is nothing display (display blank white space).

The example code to display FFT is as below.

```
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['freq', 'amp'],
        [0.3125, 12.00946904],
        [0.625, 19.77160067],
        [0.9375, 21.62805324],
        [1.25, 4.915130609],
        [1.5625, 2.409452308],
        [1.875, 1.486234231],
        [2.1875, 1.034153919],
        [2.5, 0.777528488],
        [2.8125, 0.618033989],
        [3.125, 0.512835906],
        [3.4375, 0.440704541],
        [3.75, 0.390133291],
        [4.0625, 0.354479715],
        [4.375, 0.329748464],
        [4.6875, 0.31349616],
        [5, 0.304261588],
        [5.3125, 0.301265108],
        [5.625, 0.304261588],
        [5.9375, 0.31349616],
        [6.25, 0.329748464],
        [6.5625, 0.354479715],
        [6.875, 0.390133291],
        [7.1875, 0.440704541],
        [7.5, 0.512835906],
        [7.8125, 0.618033989],
        [8.125, 0.777528488],
        [8.4375, 1.034153919],
        [8.75, 1.486234231],
        [9.0625, 2.409452308],
        [9.375, 4.915130609],
        [9.6875, 21.62805324],
        [10, 19.77160067]
      ]


      );

      var options = {
        title: 'Fast Fourier transform',
        curveType: 'function',
        legend: { position: 'bottom' }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RliI.jpg)

I tried to change the hardcoded ['freq','amp'] to fetch data from "https://iot.nipa.cloud/api/plugins/telemetry/DEVICE/{DEVICE_ID}/values/timeseries?keys=f-data"
where the result from the fetch data is in the following format (value can be any generated numbers with window size = 256)

```
{
    "f-data": [
        {
            "ts": 1681114252202,
            "value": "[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255]"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience it would be better to develop your own custom widget for that purpose. This may also be easier to integrate the timeseries data for the visualization.

Note:
The default ThingsBoard line charts uses time information on the x-axis. Therefore you have to adapt the logic in order use both *freq* and *amp* in your chart.

You find examples here:
https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/contribution/widgets-development/#time-series-example